# Android Firebase: dependencies issue

Tags: android, firebase

I tried adding this dependency...

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
```

but it says:

```
    Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0.
```

Here is my app level gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
        compileSdkVersion 27
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.newu.fireapp"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner 
            "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint layout:1.1.2'
        implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
        implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.+'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here's my top-level build file :

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
    buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'  
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }


    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Comment: Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this library

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//firebase stuff
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'

//Google Play Services
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you need to make sure you have added the google repository to your gradle configuration:

```
repositories {
    google()
}
```